# App crash when I click on device back button android

Tags: android, crash, onbackpressed

when I click on back button my application crashes

This happen in all my pages I have 3 activity and other are fragments in my application I am not getting who is creating this problem
this the full logcat I am not getting any error in my connection or any where but when I click device back button app crashes

```
09-13 15:00:32.366 3843-3843/com.example.user.soulsystem I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
09-13 15:00:32.492 3843-3843/com.example.user.soulsystem W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.user.soulsystem-1/lib/x86
09-13 15:00:47.049 3843-3843/com.example.user.soulsystem W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.user.soulsystem-1/lib/x86
09-13 15:00:47.069 3843-3843/com.example.user.soulsystem D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
09-13 15:00:47.078 3843-3843/com.example.user.soulsystem W/InstanceID/Rpc: Found 10008
09-13 15:00:47.081 3843-3843/com.example.user.soulsystem D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
09-13 15:00:47.107 3843-3843/com.example.user.soulsystem I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 9452
09-13 15:00:47.108 3843-3843/com.example.user.soulsystem I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
09-13 15:00:47.151 3843-3843/com.example.user.soulsystem I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
09-13 15:00:47.232 3843-3843/com.example.user.soulsystem W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
09-13 15:00:47.984 3843-3849/com.example.user.soulsystem W/art: Suspending all threads took: 30.062ms
09-13 15:00:47.987 3843-3843/com.example.user.soulsystem W/art: Verification of android.view.View android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean) took 495.933ms
09-13 15:00:47.988 3843-3853/com.example.user.soulsystem I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1579(368KB) AllocSpace objects, 4(80KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 2MB/3MB, paused 440us total 484.103ms
09-13 15:00:48.118 3843-4245/com.example.user.soulsystem D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true [ 
09-13 15:00:48.142  3843: 3843 D/                        HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xab1d6140, tid 3843
09-13 15:00:48.188  3843: 4245 D/                        HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaec47600, tid 4245
09-13 15:00:48.191 3843-4245/com.example.user.soulsystem I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-13 15:00:53.820 3843-3849/com.example.user.soulsystem W/art: Suspending all threads took: 87.047ms
09-13 15:00:58.115 3843-4232/com.example.user.soulsystem I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
09-13 15:02:23.664 3843-5617/com.example.user.soulsystem D/Volley: [221] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] http://192.168.1.10/soulsystem/loginall.php 0x676929bb NORMAL 1> [lifetime=3118], [size=189], [rc=200], [retryCount=1]
09-13 15:02:23.827 3843-3843/com.example.user.soulsystem D/ClientRegistration: Login Response: {"error":false,"error_msg":"Finding Consultancy","uid":"57d245518c9643.05931211","user":{"name":"Ram Waghmare","email":"ram@gmail.com","created_at":"2016-09-09 10:44:57","updated_at":null}}
09-13 15:02:23.832 3843-4245/com.example.user.soulsystem E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa31a2540
09-13 15:02:23.840 3843-3843/com.example.user.soulsystem D/Soulsystem: IN try catch
09-13 15:02:24.073 3843-3843/com.example.user.soulsystem D/SessionManager: User login session modified!
09-13 15:02:24.625 3843-3843/com.example.user.soulsystem D/SQLiteHandler: Database tables created
09-13 15:02:24.994 3843-3843/com.example.user.soulsystem D/SQLiteHandler: New user inserted into sqlite: 1
09-13 15:02:25.028 3843-3843/com.example.user.soulsystem D/Volley: [1] Request.finish: 4483 ms: [ ] http://192.168.1.10/soulsystem/loginall.php 0x676929bb NORMAL 1
09-13 15:02:25.028 3843-3843/com.example.user.soulsystem I/Choreographer: Skipped 71 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-13 15:02:25.071 3843-3843/com.example.user.soulsystem I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
09-13 15:02:25.215 3843-3843/com.example.user.soulsystem D/SQLiteHandler: Fetching user from Sqlite: {email=ram@gmail.com, name=Ram Waghmare, created_at=2016-09-09 10:44:57, uid=57d245518c9643.05931211}
09-13 15:02:25.215 3843-3843/com.example.user.soulsystem D/Soulsystem: Ram Waghmare
09-13 15:02:25.215 3843-3843/com.example.user.soulsystem D/Soulsystem: ram@gmail.com
09-13 15:02:25.268 3843-3843/com.example.user.soulsystem W/ActionBarDrawerToggle: DrawerToggle may not show up because NavigationIcon is not visible. You may need to call actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
09-13 15:02:25.489 3843-4245/com.example.user.soulsystem E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa31a2460
09-13 15:03:18.027 3843-3849/com.example.user.soulsystem W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.244ms
09-13 15:03:34.556 3843-3849/com.example.user.soulsystem W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.122ms
09-13 15:05:58.974 3843-3843/com.example.user.soulsystem D/NavigationMenu: In profile Image view

                                                                           [ 09-13 15:06:13.139  1604: 1882 D/         ]
                                                                           HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9ad14230, tid 1882
09-13 15:06:13.360 3843-3843/com.example.user.soulsystem D/FirebaseApp: Notifying background state change listeners.
09-13 15:06:13.366 3843-4245/com.example.user.soulsystem E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa31a2770
09-13 15:13:27.679 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.user.soulsystem-1/lib/x86
09-13 15:13:27.716 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
09-13 15:13:27.733 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
09-13 15:13:27.766 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 9452
09-13 15:13:27.766 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
09-13 15:13:27.795 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
09-13 15:13:27.857 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
09-13 15:13:27.937 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
09-13 15:13:28.061 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem D/SQLiteHandler: Fetching user from Sqlite: {email=ram@gmail.com, name=Ram Waghmare, created_at=2016-09-09 10:44:57, uid=57d245518c9643.05931211}
09-13 15:13:28.061 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem D/Soulsystem: Ram Waghmare
09-13 15:13:28.061 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem D/Soulsystem: ram@gmail.com
09-13 15:13:28.065 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem W/ActionBarDrawerToggle: DrawerToggle may not show up because NavigationIcon is not visible. You may need to call actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
09-13 15:13:28.071 15191-15273/com.example.user.soulsystem D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                             [ 09-13 15:13:28.075 15191:15191 D/         ]
                                                                             HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaaace1a0, tid 15191


                                                                             [ 09-13 15:13:28.107 15191:15273 D/         ]
                                                                             HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaaace5c0, tid 15273
09-13 15:13:28.111 15191-15273/com.example.user.soulsystem I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-13 15:13:31.233 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem D/FirebaseApp: Notifying background state change listeners.
09-13 15:13:31.243 15191-15273/com.example.user.soulsystem E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab1f0b70
09-13 15:13:32.265 15191-15270/com.example.user.soulsystem I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
09-13 15:13:34.089 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem D/FirebaseApp: Notifying background state change listeners.
09-13 15:13:34.188 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
09-13 15:13:34.212 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem D/SQLiteHandler: Fetching user from Sqlite: {email=ram@gmail.com, name=Ram Waghmare, created_at=2016-09-09 10:44:57, uid=57d245518c9643.05931211}
09-13 15:13:34.212 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem D/Soulsystem: Ram Waghmare
09-13 15:13:34.212 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem D/Soulsystem: ram@gmail.com
09-13 15:13:34.213 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem W/ActionBarDrawerToggle: DrawerToggle may not show up because NavigationIcon is not visible. You may need to call actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
09-13 15:13:38.875 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem D/FirebaseApp: Notifying background state change listeners.
09-13 15:13:38.879 15191-15273/com.example.user.soulsystem E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab1f0be0
09-13 15:13:41.251 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem D/FirebaseApp: Notifying background state change listeners.
09-13 15:13:41.327 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
09-13 15:13:41.393 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem D/SQLiteHandler: Fetching user from Sqlite: {email=ram@gmail.com, name=Ram Waghmare, created_at=2016-09-09 10:44:57, uid=57d245518c9643.05931211}
09-13 15:13:41.393 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem D/Soulsystem: Ram Waghmare
09-13 15:13:41.393 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem D/Soulsystem: ram@gmail.com
09-13 15:13:41.394 15191-15191/com.example.user.soulsystem W/ActionBarDrawerToggle: DrawerToggle may not show up because NavigationIcon is not visible. You may need to call actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
09-13 15:18:45.102 15191-15197/com.example.user.soulsystem W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.875ms
09-13 15:19:29.694 15191-15197/com.example.user.soulsystem W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.903ms
09-13 15:19:37.196 15191-15197/com.example.user.soulsystem W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.748ms
09-13 15:20:12.361 21039-21039/com.example.user.soulsystem W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.user.soulsystem-1/lib/x86
09-13 15:20:15.446 21039-21039/com.example.user.soulsystem W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.user.soulsystem-1/lib/x86
09-13 15:20:15.463 21039-21039/com.example.user.soulsystem D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
09-13 15:20:15.477 21039-21039/com.example.user.soulsystem D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
09-13 15:20:15.517 21039-21039/com.example.user.soulsystem I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 9452
09-13 15:20:15.517 21039-21039/com.example.user.soulsystem I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
09-13 15:20:15.541 21039-21039/com.example.user.soulsystem I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
09-13 15:20:15.606 21039-21039/com.example.user.soulsystem W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
09-13 15:20:15.777 21039-21049/com.example.user.soulsystem I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6738(1363KB) AllocSpace objects, 49(820KB) LOS objects, 41% free, 1462KB/2MB, paused 301us total 152.112ms
09-13 15:20:15.826 21039-21039/com.example.user.soulsystem I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
09-13 15:20:15.955 21039-21039/com.example.user.soulsystem D/SQLiteHandler: Fetching user from Sqlite: {email=ram@gmail.com, name=Ram Waghmare, created_at=2016-09-09 10:44:57, uid=57d245518c9643.05931211}
09-13 15:20:15.955 21039-21039/com.example.user.soulsystem D/Soulsystem: Ram Waghmare
09-13 15:20:15.955 21039-21039/com.example.user.soulsystem D/Soulsystem: ram@gmail.com
09-13 15:20:15.966 21039-21122/com.example.user.soulsystem D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                             [ 09-13 15:20:15.972 21039:21039 D/         ]
                                                                             HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaaacde40, tid 21039


                                                                             [ 09-13 15:20:16.013 21039:21122 D/         ]
                                                                             HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaec47600, tid 21122
09-13 15:20:16.016 21039-21122/com.example.user.soulsystem I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-13 15:20:17.984 21039-21045/com.example.user.soulsystem W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.043ms
09-13 15:20:42.993 21039-21039/com.example.user.soulsystem I/ListPopupWindow: Could not find method setEpicenterBounds(Rect) on PopupWindow. Oh well.
09-13 15:20:43.035 21039-21039/com.example.user.soulsystem W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
09-13 15:20:43.941 21039-21122/com.example.user.soulsystem E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa2904bc0
09-13 15:20:43.944 21039-21122/com.example.user.soulsystem D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa261c600 (MenuPopupWindow$MenuDropDownListView) with handle 0xaec52fa0
09-13 15:20:47.274 21039-21122/com.example.user.soulsystem E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa2904bc0
09-13 15:20:47.278 21039-21122/com.example.user.soulsystem D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa14a2d80 (MenuPopupWindow$MenuDropDownListView) with handle 0xab33f630
09-13 15:21:05.931 21039-21112/com.example.user.soulsystem W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.example.user.soulsystem/lib
09-13 15:21:05.992 21039-21039/com.example.user.soulsystem I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
09-13 15:21:05.999 21039-21039/com.example.user.soulsystem D/SQLiteHandler: Fetching user from Sqlite: {email=ram@gmail.com, name=Ram Waghmare, created_at=2016-09-09 10:44:57, uid=57d245518c9643.05931211}
09-13 15:21:05.999 21039-21039/com.example.user.soulsystem D/Soulsystem: Ram Waghmare
09-13 15:21:05.999 21039-21039/com.example.user.soulsystem D/Soulsystem: ram@gmail.com
09-13 15:21:06.009 21039-21122/com.example.user.soulsystem E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa2904b50
09-13 15:21:06.150 21039-21122/com.example.user.soulsystem V/RenderScript: 0xa1e12000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
09-13 15:21:07.974 21039-21122/com.example.user.soulsystem E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa2904ed0
09-13 15:21:10.712 21039-21122/com.example.user.soulsystem E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa2904f40
09-13 15:21:17.190 21039-21122/com.example.user.soulsystem E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa29035e0
09-13 15:21:27.843 21039-21122/com.example.user.soulsystem E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa2903570
09-13 15:23:27.349 21039-21045/com.example.user.soulsystem W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.127ms
09-13 15:25:31.502 25691-25691/com.example.user.soulsystem W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.user.soulsystem-1/lib/x86
09-13 15:25:35.414 25691-25691/com.example.user.soulsystem W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.user.soulsystem-1/lib/x86
09-13 15:25:35.430 25691-25691/com.example.user.soulsystem D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
09-13 15:25:35.463 25691-25691/com.example.user.soulsystem D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
09-13 15:25:35.488 25691-25691/com.example.user.soulsystem I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 9452
09-13 15:25:35.488 25691-25691/com.example.user.soulsystem I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
09-13 15:25:35.513 25691-25691/com.example.user.soulsystem I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
09-13 15:25:35.605 25691-25691/com.example.user.soulsystem W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
09-13 15:25:35.694 25691-25691/com.example.user.soulsystem I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
09-13 15:25:35.825 25691-25691/com.example.user.soulsystem D/SQLiteHandler: Fetching user from Sqlite: {email=ram@gmail.com, name=Ram Waghmare, created_at=2016-09-09 10:44:57, uid=57d245518c9643.05931211}
09-13 15:25:35.825 25691-25691/com.example.user.soulsystem D/Soulsystem: Ram Waghmare
09-13 15:25:35.825 25691-25691/com.example.user.soulsystem D/Soulsystem: ram@gmail.com
09-13 15:25:35.834 25691-25786/com.example.user.soulsystem D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                             [ 09-13 15:25:35.840 25691:25691 D/         ]
                                                                             HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb2f28600, tid 25691


                                                                             [ 09-13 15:25:35.874 25691:25786 D/         ]
                                                                             HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaec47600, tid 25786
09-13 15:25:35.877 25691-25786/com.example.user.soulsystem I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-13 15:26:48.624 25691-25697/com.example.user.soulsystem W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.614ms
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the exception you are getting?All above logs are debug or warning or info.

Comment: This is the wrong stacktrace part :-( Please scroll up in the stacktrace, find a big patch of red and paste it instead :-)

Comment: no there no error in code

Comment: Check your manifest have you kept android:noHistory="true" anywhere inside your application tag?, that might be the reason for your application crashing

Comment: no i have not used android:noHistory="true" in manifest

Comment: Override `onBackPressed()`, log a message there, add a breakpoint and debug the app to find the cause of exception.

Comment: nothing changed, still app crash

Comment: This won't resolve the exceptions, it will show you the cause of error. Have you debugged the app and followed the control flow?

Comment: This log is not the same error that you describe.

Comment: yes i did but still my app crash

Comment: Are other apps working fine? There is an option in settings where you can make apps not keep a backstack.

Comment: other apps are working well in all emulater

Comment: this one is not working. i have tested this app in 3 emulator

Answer (score 0):

Did you call `actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` in your code?

Comment: yes i used but now i am getting hamburg and the right side 3 dots

Comment: both are on the toolbar i wat just hamburger

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

there is another good reference is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781567/android-back-action-button-result-in-app-crash)